# A complicated MongoDB query (a high level of nesting)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I run MongoDB v.2.4.4-pre- under Linux. There is a collection with elements like this:

```
{
    num: 1,
    arr: [
        {
            a: 'a1',
            b: 'b1'
        },
        {
            a: 'a2',
            b: 'b2'
        }
    ]
}
```

I've got also 2 values: "numVal" and "arrVal". "numVal" is a number and "arrVal" is an array of strings.

The task is to select all the elements, where "num" == "numVal" and "a" property of each "arr" element is equal to "arrVal" element with the same index.

For example, to get the element described above, i need "numVal" = 1 and "arrVal" = ['a1', 'a2'].

Can you help me to create a correct request, please? I've got a solution based on "$where" selector, but I think, there's a better way.

Current query looks like this:

```
db.collection.find({ num: 1, $where: "this.arr.length == 2 && this.arr[0] && this.arr[0].a == 'a1' && this.arr[1] && this.arr[1].a == 'a2'" })
```

or

```
db.collection.find({ num: 1, 'arr.a': { $all: [ 'a1', 'a2' ] }, arr: { $size: 2 }, $where: "this.arr[0].a == 'a1' && this.arr[1].a == 'a2'" })
```

Number of items, filtered by "$where" in most cases would be 1 or 2, maximal quantity is near 20.

P.S. I can't reorganize my DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can successfully use next query:

```
db.collection.find({ num: 1, arr: { $size: 2 }, 'arr.0.a': 'a1', 'arr.1.a': 'a2' })
```